# How to render a component for multiple routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have a component which i want to render for multiple routes with URL params. I am using react-router v4. Right now I am using three different routes.

```js
<Route
    path="/"
    render={path => (
        <Component
          path={path}
        /> 
    )}
/>
<Route
    path="/a/:urlParams1"
    render={path => (
        <Component
          path={path}
        /> 
    )}
/>
<Route
    path="/a/:urlParams1/b/:urlParams2"
    render={path => (
        <Component
          path={path}
        /> 
    )}
/>
```

are there any better way to render a component for multiple routes with URL params? I tried using regex for path but i couldn't access the params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently can't send an array of paths as a path but there is an open feature request for this [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5866).

I can suggest a neater version for your problem just for now with this approach:

```
const componentRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/"
  },
  {
    path: "/a/:urlParams1"
  },
  {
    path: "/a/:urlParams1/b/:urlParams2"
  }
]


<Switch>
  {
    componentRoutes.map(route => (
      <Route key={route.path} exact 
             path={route.path} 
             render={path => (<Component path={path}/>)}/>
    ))
   }
</Switch>
```

You can remove the Switch component, its just for the example.